# iPhone : How to find Dates between two selected dates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate

In my app, I am getting two dates.

For Example,

> 1st Date : 28-10-2011
>
> 2nd Date : 2-11-2011

Now I want to all dates between this two selected date.

So it should be,

> 28-10-2011
>
> 29-10-2011
>
> 30-10-2011
>
> 1-11-2011
>
> 2-11-2011

How can I get this using NSDate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357257/simplest-way-to-loop-between-two-nsdates-on-iphone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `dateWithTimeInterval:SinceDate:`

```
NSMutableArray dates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *curDate = startDate;
while([curDate timeIntervalSince1970] <= [endDate timeIntervalSince1970]) //you can also use the earlier-method
{
    [dates addObject:curDate];
    curDate = [MSDate dateWithTimeInterval:86400 sinceDate:curDate]; 86400 = 60*60*24
}
//here maybe an additional check if the enddate has to be inserted or not
```

Comment: Does adding 86400 seconds also work for days on which Daylight Savings occurs? Such days could be an hour longer or shorter...

Answer (score 3):

Look at `NSDateComponents` and `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`, this is what I use and it works pretty good. Make sure to watch out for years that are leap years.

UPDATE: I would use thomas's example. It works better than mine and it is a lot easier to read.

Comment: But his is less reliable around clock changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your strings to NSDate objects using NSDateFormatter, then use NSDate's ealierDate: and laterDate: methods to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate  *endDate = [today addTimeInterval:10.0*60.0*60.0*24.0]; // end date 10 days ahead
while (YES) {

    startDate= [startDate addTimeInterval:1.0*60.0*60.0*24.0];
    NSLog(@"%@   --  %@",endDate,startDate);

    if([startDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedDescending) break;
}
```