# How do you generate a random date in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'd like to generate a random date between two dates -- for example a random date between today and 60 days from now. How do I do that?

**UPDATE**

Using information from the answers, I came up with this method, which I  use quite often:

```
// Generate a random date sometime between now and n days before day.
// Also, generate a random time to go with the day while we are at it.
- (NSDate *) generateRandomDateWithinDaysBeforeToday:(NSInteger)days
{
    int r1 = arc4random_uniform(days);
    int r2 = arc4random_uniform(23);
    int r3 = arc4random_uniform(59);

    NSDate *today = [NSDate new];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = 
             [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
    [offsetComponents setDay:(r1*-1)];
    [offsetComponents setHour:r2];
    [offsetComponents setMinute:r3];

    NSDate *rndDate1 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents 
                                                  toDate:today options:0];

    return rndDate1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to loop between two NSDates on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357257/simplest-way-to-loop-between-two-nsdates-on-iphone)

Comment: I've no idea what you are thinking @lulius Cæsar, but this question is not even vaguely similar to looping between two dates...

Comment: Same code, refactored and documented https://gist.github.com/eirnym/c9526a045556e4d8464b41a367843e3c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Generate a random number between 1 and 60

   ```
   int r = arc4random_uniform(60) + 1;

   // Usage : arc4random_uniform(hi - lo + 1) + lo
   ```
2. Get current date

   ```
   [NSDate date];
   ```
3. Use `NSDateComponents` to subtract the random number from your `days` component and generate a new date.

Comment: While probably not a major deal here, using % almost always biases random numbers. The function you want is arc4random_uniform().

Comment: arc4random_uniform(upper_bound) just returns an integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than upper_bound such that the distribution is uniform. That is to say that all values in the range are equally likely.

Comment: @RobNapier : Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: Great information. Thanks! I had no idea how to approach this problem. Now, not only do I have a good solution, but I learned something about random number generation! arc4random()'s non-uniform distribution (which is particularly bad when creating BOOLs) has always bothered me.

Answer (score 17):

Get a random number and use it as a time interval, then add that to the start date. E.g.

```
NSTimeInterval timeBetweenDates = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSTimeInterval randomInterval = ((NSTimeInterval)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * timeBetweenDates;

NSDate *randomDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:randomInterval];
```

Comment: if you are getting an error about ARC4RANDOM_MAX, replace it with 0x100000000 or use #define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000

Comment: BTW, I think this should be the accepted answer as it solves a lot more use cases for random dates than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a **Swift 4.x** extension that will allow you to specify a period of days, which it will then use to find a random `Date` before or after the current date.

```
extension Date {
    static func randomDate(range: Int) -> Date {
        // Get the interval for the current date
        let interval =  Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        // There are 86,400 milliseconds in a day (ignoring leap dates)
        // Multiply the 86,400 milliseconds against the valid range of days
        let intervalRange = Double(86_400 * range)
        // Select a random point within the interval range
        let random = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(intervalRange)) + 1)
        // Since this can either be in the past or future, we shift the range
        // so that the halfway point is the present
        let newInterval = interval + (random - (intervalRange / 2.0))
        // Initialize a date value with our newly created interval
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: newInterval)
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
Date.randomDate(range: 500) // Any date that is +/- 500 days from the current date
```

Running this 10 times produces:

```
2019-03-15 01:45:52 +0000
2018-12-20 02:09:51 +0000
2018-06-28 10:28:31 +0000
2018-08-02 08:13:01 +0000
2019-01-25 07:04:18 +0000
2018-08-30 22:37:52 +0000
2018-10-05 19:38:22 +0000
2018-11-30 04:51:18 +0000
2019-03-24 07:27:39 +0000
```

Answer (score 5):

Here framework does a good job at generating random date. But in Swift: 
https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom/blob/master/SwiftRandom/Randoms.swift

```
public extension NSDate {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func randomWithinDaysBeforeToday(days: Int) -> NSDate {
        let today = NSDate()

        guard let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) else {
            print("no calendar \"NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian\" found")
            return today
        }

        let r1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(days))
        let r2 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))
        let r3 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))
        let r4 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))

        let offsetComponents = NSDateComponents()
        offsetComponents.day = Int(r1) * -1
        offsetComponents.hour = Int(r2)
        offsetComponents.minute = Int(r3)
        offsetComponents.second = Int(r4)

        guard let rndDate1 = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(offsetComponents, toDate: today, options: []) else {
            print("randoming failed")
            return today
        }
        return rndDate1
    }

    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random() -> NSDate {
        let randomTime = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max))
        return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: randomTime)
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice extension! Shouldn't r3 and r4 random numbers be randomised up to 59?

Comment: Ummm yeah :D feel free to send a pull request on github

Comment: Okay, pull request sent. By the way, SwiftRandom is sooooooo useful, thanks for the suggestion! Are you the author?

Comment: Broken link! @Esqarrouth

Answer (score 2):

Use seconds. Pseudocode:

```
1 Generate a random integer between 0 and (60 * 60 * 24 * 60)
2 Get the unixtime in seconds for the current time
3 Add your random integer
4 Convert this integer back to a date
```

Comment: Days can be longer or shorter than 24 hours, due to the start and stop of Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: Ah, yes that is correct. This method will produce a random date within a 60 day period +/- an hour, which is acceptable in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3.x +**

```
public extension Date {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func randomWithinDaysBeforeToday(days: Int) -> Date {
        let today = Date()
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

        let r1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(days))
        let r2 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))
        let r3 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))
        let r4 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(23))

        let offsetComponents = NSDateComponents()
        offsetComponents.day = Int(r1) * -1
        offsetComponents.hour = Int(r2)
        offsetComponents.minute = Int(r3)
        offsetComponents.second = Int(r4)

        let rndDate1 = gregorian.date(byAdding: offsetComponents as DateComponents, to: today)
        return rndDate1!
    }

    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random() -> Date {
        let randomTime = TimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max))
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: randomTime)
    }
}
```

<sub>P.S. [Esqarrouth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2589276/esqarrouth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33077138/1603234) corrected for latest Swift.</sub>